# Execute promises when all resolved (as DB Transactions)

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have two promises that need to act as Transactions, if one of them fails, a "rollback" should occur.

For example: When I create a user I want to send a confirmation email, but what happens if there is an error on sending the email, the user will be created but will never get a confirmation.

```
await saveUser(user)
await sendEmail(user)
```

If I switch the order, what happens when something goes wrong on creating the user? It will get a confirmation.

```
await sendEmail(user)
await saveUser(user)
```

I thought a `Promise.all` will do the trick, but it doesn't.

```
await Promise.all([saveUser(user), sendEmail(user)]);
```

Is there a way to execute promises as transactions on Javascript? Promises should execute if and only if both of them resolve.

Comment: Seems to me that the first is the way to go: create the user, then send the email, sequentially.  Just wrap the two calls in a try/catch, and in the catch rollback.  (How you begin/rollback transactions depends on your DB layer.)

Comment: Not sure if this is even worth mentioning, but it's a bit strange to rollback the user creation because a confirmation email fails.  Someone signs up for your site during a time where there's a temporary email outage, wouldn't you still want the user?  You can always queue up the email part, or re-create the email when service is restored.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that into the catch, I let the user know when a user already exists, if I delete the user I will be deleting users. I'm thinking about handle errors by type, not sure

Comment: Not following where the deletion comes in.  If `saveUser` fails, the user should not have been inserted, i.e. there's no reason for a delete.  If the user already exists then there's no reason to delete the existing user.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. The problem is when email fails, the user will never get the verification email and won't be able to log in

Comment: Promises don't provide a transaction mechanism. Your database does.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in 'transaction mechanism' in JavaScript like there is in some databases. You cannot go back in time to undo operations which you have already performed. If you wish to reverse the effects of `saveUser` when `sendEmail` fails, then you need to create another function, such as `unsaveUser`, and invoke it if `sendEmail` fails.

This can be done in the following way:

Using Promises:

```
saveUser(user)
.then(() => sendEmail(user))
.catch(err => {
  if (err.message === "Email Error") { // Check the exception to determine if the email failed
    unsaveUser(user);
  }
});

// This will only send the email if 'saveUser' was successful, and call 'unsaveUser' if email fails
```

Same thing using Async/Await:

```
try {
  await saveUser(user);
  sendEmail(user);
} catch(err) {
  if (err.message === "Email Error") { // Check the exception to determine if the email failed
    unsaveUser(user);
  }
}
```

For this example to work, in your async `sendEmail` function, you must `throw new Error("Email Error");` upon detecting an error. If you are using resolve/reject, it would be `reject(new Error("Email Error"));`.

I hope this is clear to you and helps you resolve your issue.

Comment: Yup, I supposed it wasn't possible. Thanks for your response

Comment: @araujo Then you should mark as the correct answer